# How do I set the timezone for Subsonic audit fields?

Tags: timezone, subsonic, date, audit

I like the fact that Subsonic automatically updates my audit field "CreatedOn" but it seems to only do it in server time. Is there a way to instruct Subsonic to save the audit dates as UTC instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the provider **useUTC="true"**
But it's so long ago I can't remember if it works.

```
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="TAProvider" 
     templateDirectory="..\..\ExternalResources\SubSonicCustomTemplates">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="TAProvider" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" 
         connectionStringName="TA" generatedNamespace="TA.DAL" useUTC="true" 
         useSPs="false" generateLazyLoads="false"/>
  </providers>
</SubSonicService>
```

For me, if a field is ever UTC time I always call it xxxUTC just cause I get terribly confused with anything to do with timezones, so I modified the Controller template Save method as below. Basically just check for the column and set it as required...

```
            <%=tbl.ClassName %> oldItem = null;
            if (item.<%=tbl.PrimaryKey.PropertyName%> != <%=emptyVariableText%>)
                oldItem = new <%=tbl.ClassName %>(item.<%=tbl.PrimaryKey.PropertyName%>);

            if (item.<%=tbl.PrimaryKey.PropertyName%> == <%=emptyVariableText%>)
            {
                            item.IsNew = true;
<%  if (tbl.Columns.Contains("CreatedOnUTC"))
    { 
%>                    item.CreatedOnUTC = DateTime.UtcNow; 
<%  } 
    if (tbl.Columns.Contains("CreatedOn")) // just checking
    { 
%>                  error: createdon column. fix and rerun template 
<%  } 
    if (tbl.Columns.Contains("CreatedByID"))
    { 
%>                    item.CreatedByID = taUser.telUser.TelUserID; 
<%  } 
%>
            }
<%  if (tbl.Columns.Contains("ModifiedOnUTC"))  
    { 
%>                item.ModifiedOnUTC = DateTime.UtcNow; 
<%} 
    if (tbl.Columns.Contains("ModifiedByID"))
    {   
%>                item.ModifiedByID = taUser.telUser.TelUserID; 
<%  } 
%>            
            try
            {
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and let you know